# Upload file to AWS S3 using Boto3 with full access permissions

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

Hi i need help in setting permissions to an object when uploading to S3. I want to make it public read/write.

I have a function as follows.

```
def UploadFile(self, destFilePath, data):
        self._bucket.put_object(Key=destFilePath, Body=data, ACL='public-read-write')
```

When it runs, i have a permissions error.

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: It appears that the application does not have sufficient permissions to upload the file. How is the application receiving the credentials? Is it running on an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned Role, or are you passing credentials via a file? What permissions have been given to the Role or the credentials? What is the Bucket Policy on the target bucket? You can test the permissions by running an `aws s3 cp` command with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) on the same system.

Comment: Hi could you teach me how to pass credentials using a file? I did not know how to do that does i resulted to making the file have full access

Comment: I have my access and secret key with me

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand [how your application can access AWS credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html).

When making an API call to AWS, credentials must be provided to authenticate the person or application making the request to AWS. These credentials can identify:

- A **User** defined in AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM), who has static credentials
- A **Role** defined in AWS IAM, which does not have credentials but is **assumed** by a User or an AWS service
- **Temporary permissions** created by the AWS Security Token Service

These entities are assigned **permissions** that grant the right to make particular API calls against particular resources. For example, permissions might be granted to download data from an Amazon S3 bucket, start/stop an Amazon EC2 instance or modify security settings. These permissions are defined in **policies**.

There are several ways you could provide credentials to your Python application:

- By running the application on an **Amazon EC2 instance that was assigned a Role** upon launch: The application can [retrieve credentials via the Instance Metadata service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials). (The best option)
- By providing credentials in a **configuration file** (Always dangerous, since they could be accidentally checked-into a source code repository)
- By passing credentials via **Environment variables** (Good for local computers)

Therefore, if you are receiving an `AccessDenied` error, you should:

- Identify how the application was retrieving credentials
- Look at the policies associated with those credentials
- Update the policies to grant the necessary access

See: [Boto documentation: Configuring Credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html) and [IAM documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_identity-management.html)